# What does the following definition of a basis set stand for?

Tags: general-topology

I have the following extract from a text

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Topological spaces. Consider the topology on the
>   set, $Z = (X \times Y) \cup \{a,b\}$ induced by a basis, whose
>   elements are subsets $S$ of the form $S = \{(x,y)\} \in  X \times Y$ ...

I am confused by the definition of the subsets $S$. Does it contain one or more then one element of $X \times Y$ ? I think it contains only single element of the form $(x,y)$ but I am not sure.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yes, the set $\{(x,y)\}$ contains only the single point $(x,y)$. Oh, but note that one would write $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ or, alternatively, $\{(x,y)\}\subseteq X\times Y$, but not $\{(x,y)\}\in X\times Y$.

Comment: Yes, I thought that it was a bit strangely phrased.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to follow, I suppose. But indeed, every element of $S$ that you mention is a singleton. So the author intends for the new topology to have isolated points at almost all points (namely those of $X \times Y$). The new points $a$ and $b$ will presumably have other neighbourhoods?

Comment: Yes, the subsets $S$ which contain $a$ are defined $S = Z \setminus A$ where $A$ contains points of the form $X \times B$ where $B \subset Y$ is finite. Similarly, for $b$ but only in this case $S = B \times Y$ and $B$ is a finite subset of $X$. Do you think this changes anything ? Thanks!

Comment: No, it confirms my hypothesis. $X \times Y \subset Z$ consists of isolated points. Weird (to me): the author doesn't use the original topology on $X$ or $Y$. So why assume these are spaces (and not sets)?